# Python pwntools recvuntil regex

Tags: python, regex

Given the code below, how would I go about doing some regex on what's passed onto `recvuntil`? The response is spread over multiple lines and can have repeated text

```
from pwn import *

r = remote("localhost", 6666)
r.recvuntil ('SOME TEXT (.*) SOME MORE TEXT') # This is always the last line
# Grab the regex'd text
```

So if the line is

```
SOME TEXT CAT SOME MORE TEXT
```

We grab `CAT`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a regex to extract the word `CAT` from `SOME TEXT CAT SOME MORE TEXT`, you can use this:

```
SOME TEXT ([^\s]+) SOME MORE TEXT
```

It matches every character except whitespace (`\s`) between `SOME TEXT` and `SOME MORE TEXT`.

---

**Here is an exectuable example:**

```js
var text = "SOME TEXT CAT SOME MORE TEXT";
var regex = /SOME TEXT ([^\s]+) SOME MORE TEXT/g;
var match = regex.exec(text);

while(match !== null) {
  console.log(match[1]);
  match = regex.exec(text);
}
```

Comment: It's first thing on a Monday morning but that looks like JavaScript rather than Python, but I guess same principle would apply?

Comment: This is just a JavaScript demonstration of how the regular expression works. Regular expressions are implemented in various programming languages quite similar.

Comment: Ok thanks - I know about the JS implementation but was wondering how to work with Python in the specific example of receiving data. With that said, your post has just made something click on how to do it properly in Python so thanks!